# FreeBSD pkg installation operation timed out error

Tags: package-management, freebsd, timeout

I'm trying to install some packages in FreeBSD. I got this timed out error during installation of gnome3 also.Now I'm trying to install Firefox and again same error. Can anyone give me solution for this ?

Comment: Some more info are needed about your issue: FreeBSD version, exact error message, how the packages are built or fetched, ...

Answer (score 0):

Shows detailed debug info

```
pkg --debug install <pkg-name>
```